# Layered costmap

Tags: ros, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a newbie to ROS and especially the 2d_nav stack. So please pardon me if my query sounds to petty.

I have been reading the literature about the Layered costmap recently. I would like to use something similar. To be precise, I would like to add one layer and use the information in this layer during the planning process.

However, I am not very clear yet how the layered costmap works. Are there different layeres existing and the information at all layers is combined to form a final layer which is basically combination of say the inflation radii at different layers? Or information about each layer is maintained and fe to the planner? Or its something else?

Please let me know if you have any information about this.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197300/layered-costmap/) by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

David Lu et. Al published a [paper on the layered costmaps](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Edvl1/publications/LayeredCostmaps.pdf) which describes how the costmap update works at a high level (with pictures too). I've recently added a link to it in the source code as well.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2014-11-17**:
First of all I apologize for the delay in reply. Thank you for the information. I will have a look over it and get back to you if I have more queries?

**Comment by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) on 2014-11-23**:
Also take a look at: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials